# facebook An access token is required to request this resource

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using facebook app to upload videos to user walls.

Note:
      I have user permission for publish.
      Script is fine and works for small videos with success.
      I have user extended token with validity 60 days and I debugged my token and its fine with validity and have posting permissions.

my script for posting is working fine with small videos.

**ISSUE**

```
     When I try to upload more than 100 MB video with only 5 or 6 min length I receive following api errors.
```

> An access token is required to request this resource.
>
> An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

## NOTE

> When I apply small videos it works successfully.

## TEST

I added same video with same length with two different sizes one is 720P with ~121MB and other is 480P with ~42MB both are same video.

But 480P with ~42MB uploaded successfully and 720P with ~121MB failed and api throws this exactly error in error log

> An access token is required to request this resource.

```
$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$data = $facebook->api('/'.$user_id.'/videos', 'post', $args);
```

Comment: So. Isn't the "An access token is required to request this resource." error message clear for you?

Comment: I applied the access token and access token is valid. but I am receiving this error for morethan 100MB videos

Comment: if facebook requires you a token then either it's not valid or API bug.

Comment: I checked the validity using this. and it is valid token....                                  $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token='.$USER_TOKEN.'&access_token='.$APP_TOKEN;
$a = file_get_contents($url);

Comment: Then try to file an API bug

Comment: This is the code I am using: I edited the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved.
We placed this as a bug in facebook bug. 
We used the code provided by Facebook support team and issue was resolved.
Facebook support response:

> "We were not able to replicate this issue.
>   If you are still experiencing issues, can you setup a testbench on your server and run the below example to verify your implementation? If you can provide a link to the testbench with the modified code below, that would be helpful in replicating this issue.
>
> Main code:
>
> https://github.com/eosgood/fbphpsdk
>
> Modification for video post:
>
> https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6872121
>
> We tested this on our servers with a 177MB MKV video without any failures."